# R: Rounding error when extracting ending digit from a number

Tags: r, data.table

In R I want to extract the ending digit of a number in integer format. However, the output of my code contains rounding errors. I guess this is caused by the `as.integer` function but I don't know how to fix this. Also note that my actual dataset is about 10GB so speed is quite important here.

```
library("data.table")
data<-c(72.15,72.02,72.00,71.90,71.85,71.74,72.60)
DT<-data.table(data)
DT[,end_digit:=as.integer((data*100))%%10]

    data end_digit
1: 72.15         5
2: 72.02         2
3: 72.00         0
4: 71.90         0
5: 71.85         4
6: 71.74         3
7: 72.60         9
```

To be clear, the expected output is:

```
    data end_digit
1: 72.15         5
2: 72.02         2
3: 72.00         0
4: 71.90         0
5: 71.85         5
6: 71.74         4
7: 72.60         0
```

Comment: Can't you try `DT[, end_digit:= substr(data*100,4,4)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `round`, since `as.integer` truncates.

```
DT[,end_digit:=round(data*100)%%10]
DT
    data end_digit
1: 72.15         5
2: 72.02         2
3: 72.00         0
4: 71.90         0
5: 71.85         5
6: 71.74         4
7: 72.60         0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DT[, end_digit := round(( data * 100 )) %% 10]
```